# Support for EJB2 with Jboss 5CR2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss5.x, ejb-2.x

How I can configure Jboss 5 to support EJB2?

I'm testing the new release of jboss (5) and need to deploy my old EJB2

Answer (score 2):

EJB3/J2EE5 compliance require that the application server maintain compatibility and interoperability with EJB2.  The Jboss "default" mode already supports EJB2 as far as I know.